# Vaadin - How to have two columns of data (Gridlayout with field and Label data with wrapping text)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to create a `CustomComponent` where I have two columns (possibly four) where the two columns are rows of `Labels`. The first column is the identifier such as "Firstname: ", "Lastname: ", etc. and the second column is the actual value for the identifier such as "John", "Smith", etc.

I'm using a `GridLayout` so that the data is all line up nicely (for example John is lined up with Smith on the next line).

The problem I'm having is that I want the second column to take the remainder of the space width wise and have the text wrap to the next line when it's too long. So for example if I have a Comments `Label` that is a paragraph long I want the text to wrap but it just keeps going off the screen.

Now I understand that [the `Label` needs to have a defined width to be able to wrap the text](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/126872/181018) however I can't figure out how to use this to make the text in the labels in a grid wrap. I've tried everything I could think of.

My code is:

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
gridLayout.setColumns(2);
gridLayout.setColumnExpandRatio(0, 1f);

gridLayout.addComponent(new Label("Firstname"));
gridLayout.addComponent(firstnameValueLabel);
gridLayout.addComponent(new Label("Lastname"));
gridLayout.addComponent(lastnameValueLabel);
// and so on.

VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
verticalLayout.addComponent(myHeaderComponent);
verticalLayout.addComponent(gridLayout);
```

I've tried everything I could think of to have the `valueLabel` (`firstnameValueLabel`, etc.) text wrap but nothing seems to work. I've tried to assign specific sizes to the `GridLayout`, the `VerticalLayout`, rather than 100%, and so on but without any success. I am using a `VerticalLayout` because I have additional stuff above the data.

Perhaps using a `GridLayout` isn't the best option, maybe there's a better way to line up forms that aren't fields. Although `FormLayout` would be perfect it only seems to work with input fields.

In any case how should I implement this so that the `Label` text wraps?

Comment: If you add labels with a caption the FormLayout works just fine.  What errors did you get?

Comment: When I wrote this question I hadn't realized the caption was the fieldname for the Label. That being said I'm struggling with how to create forms with multiple columns where you sometimes want to expand some of the fields over multiple columns and sometimes not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a combination of things. First the biggest tip I can offer is to look at [Consume available space in Vaadin Gridlayout, but consider line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270487/consume-available-space-in-vaadin-gridlayout-but-consider-line-breaks)

After that the code above was using `setCaption()` when it should've been using `setValue()`.

Combining these two things resolved the issue and the text wrapped.

Answer (score -2):

Do

```
int colums = 2;
int rows = 0;
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(colums,rows);
```

hope that helped

Comment: Welcome to SO!  This does not answer the question.  OP's code sample includes setting columns & rows.  OP is asking about spacing & alignment.  Additionally, if you are going to post an answer you should not post code-only answers (although there's nothing prohibiting them) and instead post code with comments explaining it and/or an additional explanation on WHY it'll solve their issue.